# Need help analyzing ASP.Net Core 3.1 memory dump

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, memory-management, memory-leaks, dotmemory

I'm prepared to pay for help on this!!

My ASP.Net Core 3.1 application starts at around 450MB, and gradually runs up to around 4.5GB (and I suspect it would grow even more if more memory were available to it).

I have taken memory dumps at various stages, and analyzing them with [dotMemory](https://www.jetbrains.com/dotmemory/) seems to show that JsonSerialiserOptions is a prime suspect:

[image: largest retained size]

Drilling to `JsonSerializerOptions` shows the 3 instances.  Two have negligible numbers, and if I further drill into the one of the 3 with the highest memory use, it's Key Retention Path shows this:
[image: Key Retention Paths]

And this is where I need help.  I really don't know what to make of these retention paths.  I'm expecting that if the problem is in my code, I should find some class of my app at the bottom of a retention path?  I need help trying to figure out from these retention paths where in my code the problem may be.

Comment: SUGGESTION: Familiarize yourself with the MSVS [Memory Usage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/memory-usage?view=vs-2019) diagnostic tool

Comment: Gotta admit I'm a bit confused, given that dotMemory is a commercial product with a wealth  of support info, documentation, YouTube videos, howtos and a company support team backing it up, why you need to ask this question in this way (or at all). Do you have any undisclosed affiliation with jetbrains? If you're up for paying anyone, perhaps buying the full product from jb and getting their steer on how to use it would be most effective

Comment: It's not a dotMemory product support issue.  It's a general question about understanding what the Retention Path is telling me.  I have reviewed the dotMemory online documentation and examples.  And based on that, I added the statement in my question that if the problem is in my code, I'd expect to see one of my own project's classes in the retention path.  But all I'm seeing are core library classes.  Am I to believe the problem is in the .Net Core DI system?

Comment: Enable gathering of allocations info in dotMemory and look at what stack trace instances of JsonSerializerOptions are created. It will tip you which objects you should release or dispose to avoid keeping them in the memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem was due to a bug in which a flexible, run-time-defined database query was retuning instances of type `Object`, instead of instances of type `dynamic`.  The JsonSerializer correctly does NOT cache `dynamic` types, but it DOES cache `Object` types.

So each time the query ran, the JsonSerializer was caching the `Object` structure.  The fix was to ensure the the database query returned `dynamic` types instead of `Object` types.

Comment: The `dynamic` type stops being `dynamic` after compilation and the CLR treats it as if it was just an `object` which I believe has nothing the do with your memory leaking. I think you are on the right track but perhaps drew your conclusions a bit too early? :)

Comment: Nope, this change definitely solved my memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your problem relates to the reload change token. A memory leak reported way back in .NET 2.1 - for more details follow: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/6102

**but**

if you're targeting a newer version of the .Net I'd recommend inspecting your `ConfigureServices()` method (*`Startup.cs`*) and eliminating [misconfigured services lifetimes](https://andrewlock.net/the-dangers-and-gotchas-of-using-scoped-services-when-configuring-options-in-asp-net-core/) and/or [captive dependencies](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/02/captive-dependency/).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback; it reminded me to add my findings as the solution.